# jQuery Autocomplete bugs with AJAX and links

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So, my code is:

```
$( "#global-search" ).catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: "globalsearch.php",
    select: function( event, ui ) { 
        window.location.href = ui.item.value;
        $( "#global-search" ).val('');
    }
});
```

And the problem is that I'm using jquery catcomplete, and when I click the result, it works on the first time and it goes, for example, to `localhost/#!/mylink1`.

Then I try again to search on my catcomplete, and when I click the result, the link it doesn't work.

And when I click the result, the input doesn't empty the value, and the value changes to the result's link, for example, my input's value turns into `#!/mylink/` instead of nothing.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to mess with the input's value while autocomplete is atached to it...

Answer (score 0):

When you change the location of your browser, what else is the page doing? I mean, is it refreshing the content? If the content is being refreshed/replaced may be the #global-search is not being initialized again with the catcomplete function.

Regarding its behavior with the value, try to add a event.preventDefault() on the function's body.

Comment: I already solved my problem replacing the jquery's search for a code I did by myself. anyway, thanks for your answer!